# CNN: understanding weights output channel argument

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

```py
weights = {
  # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
  'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
  # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
  'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
  # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
  'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
  # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
  'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]))
}
```

My question is:
how do I calculate number of feature/channel output, in this case it's 32 in first layer, 64 in second and 1024 in third? And what effect will it make  if I add more or less number than 32, 64, 1024 in my CNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restrictions of this CNN model are the following:

- `7x7` is determined by the input image size. In this case, it's `28x28` after 2 downsampling (pooling) operations.
- The number of features (`32`, `64`) in the conv layer can be arbitrary, but it has to correspond to the depth value of the next layer. So, if you change `32` to `48` in `wc1`, you have to also change `32` to `48` in `wc2`.
- The same about the size of the FC-layer: `1024` in `wd1` has to correspond to `1024` in `out`.

Other than this, you *can* set any values, though it *may or may not* improve network performance. Often the researches set them as large as possible so that the model still fits into GPU memory, because bigger models tend to learn better. Also it makes sense to increase the size from the early layers further down, to capture the complexity of the learned features, i.e. the variety in the second layer is larger than in the first.

Answer (score 0):

As the number of filters e.g. 32, 64, 128, 1024 is a design decision, the model designer decides the number of filters to use. In this case, you. Typically powers of 2 is used 2^5 = 32, 2^6 = 64 etc. Different number of filters would obviously have an impact on the number of operations required for computation in addition to impacting the number of parameters that the model will have to learn.

e.g. 10 filters with dimension 5x5x1 (height x width x channels) would have (5 x 5 x 1 + 1) x 10 = 110 parameters to train. Note that + 1 is for the bias term.

I suggest reading the below in particular the section on ConvNet architectures.
http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#architectures

For convolutional arithmetic I found "A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning" resourceful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285